# Coercing FullSimplify to groups results

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

Is there a way to coerce FullSimplify to group the second result (below) to be similar to the first result?

```
eqDa01 = fCond + fFwhdrain + fExtToDa == fFw;
eqDa02 = fCond hCond + fFwhdrain hFwhdrain + fExtToDa hExtToDa == fFw hFw;
solDa = Solve[{eqDa01, eqDa02}, {fCond, fExtToDa}][[1]] // FullSimplify;
eqDafCond = solDa[[1, 2]]
eqDafExtToDa = solDa[[2, 2]]
```

Below are the results
[image]

would like to see the second result to be something like the following, which is similar to the first result.

(fFw (hCond - hFw ) + fFwhdrain (hFwhdrain - hCond) ) (hCond - hExtToDa)

Note after changing the symbols to something less verbose, the results are still not consistently grouped:

```
eqDa01 = fa + fb + fc == fd;
eqDa02 = fa ha + fb hb + fc hc == fd hd;
solDa = Solve[{eqDa01, eqDa02}, {fa, fb}][[1]] // FullSimplify
eqDafCond = solDa[[1, 2]]
eqDafExtToDa = solDa[[2, 2]]
```

[image]

Now for the first result, would like to see something like
( fc (hb - hc) + fd (hd - hb) ) / (ha - hb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eqDa01 = fCond + fFwhdrain + fExtToDa == fFw;
eqDa02 = fCond hCond + fFwhdrain hFwhdrain + fExtToDa hExtToDa == fFw hFw;
solDa = Solve[{eqDa01, eqDa02}, {fCond, fExtToDa}][[1]] // FullSimplify;

eqDafCond = solDa[[1, 2]]

(* (fFw (-hExtToDa + hFw) + fFwhdrain (hExtToDa - hFwhdrain))/(hCond - hExtToDa) *)
```

For the second result use [`Collect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html) on the numerator

```
eqDafExtToDa = MapAt[Collect[#, {fFw, fFwhdrain}] &, solDa[[2, 2]], 2]

(* (fFw (hCond - hFw) + fFwhdrain (-hCond + hFwhdrain))/(hCond - hExtToDa) *)
```

Verifying equivalence,

```
eqDafExtToDa == solDa[[2, 2]] // Simplify

(* True *)
```